# How to make a loop for select by attribute?

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7

I am trying to pull out a sample out of a geodatabase file. I have 100800 sample and I need to select 28 records, basically every 3600, I am going to start with FID=0 and go from there.
Unfortunately I haven't been able to make it work.
this is what I have done so far. anyone can give me a hint, it's gonna be a huge help.

```
import arcpy, sys, os

Input=sys.argv[1]
field=sys.argv[2]
counts=sys.argv[3]
output=sys.argv[4]

def deleteMe(fc):
    if arcpy.Exists(fc):
        arcpy.Delete_management(fc)
    return fc


cursor =arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Input,field)
for row in cursor:
    a=row[0]
    while row:
        x=a+3600

    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Input, deleteMe("lyr"))
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("lyr", "NEW_SELECTION",a)

#arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("lyr", "ADD_TO_SELECTION",x)



arcpy.CopyFeatures_management ("lyr", deleteMe(output))
```

Comment: Skip through with an incrementing variable, when you hit your target value keep that OID (OIDlist.append(str(row[0])) and reset the counter to 0. Then use the query string "OBJECTID IN (" + ",".join(OIDlist) + ")".. it's that or (if your OIDs are unique and ascending) OBECTID MOD 3600 = 0

Comment: yes, just what I was thinking.  OP mentioned a geodatabase so I wrote my answer for non-consecutive OBJECTIDs.  I didn't think of using MOD in the query though, if it was a shapefile that would be great.

Comment: I know @mr.adam, the mod(FID,3600) would do it for sure in a shapefile as FIDs are compressed on save. Note the change of syntax for the mod operator in shapefiles. If you think that's fun try to select out a random 10% of features... now that was fun!

Answer (score 1):

How about just making a list of the OBJECTID's you want and making it into a query?

```
## start with list of all objectids
all_oids = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Input,"OBJECTID")]

## make list of every 3600th objectid
oids = []
for index, oid in enumerate(range(len(all_oids))):
    if index % 3600 == 0:
        oids.append(oid)

## make sql query
qry = '"OBJECTID" IN ({0})'.format(".join(oids))

## deal with the datasets
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Input, deleteMe("lyr"))
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", qry)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management ("lyr", deleteMe(output))
```

[Enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) is a super useful function.  It iterates a list and also returns the index of each item. You're using it here to run through the list of OBJECTIDs and if the index is a factor of 3600 the oid appended to a list.  Then use that list to create a query that you can apply to the feature layer.

Comment: Where does i come into it? That's basically what I said but you need to set i=0 to start and then i+=1 in the loop.

Comment: oops, was from an earlier version of the answer, will update...